# how to Convert Data.dataview (vb) to c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

how to convert the following code to c#?

```
Dim questionIDdata As Data.DataView = DSquestionID.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
Dim questionID As Integer = questionIDdata.Item(0).Row(0);
```

Comment: Whats the problem with using an online converter. it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of online converters that will syntax transform vb to c# for you, by the way..

```
var questionIDdata = (DataView)DSquestionID.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
var questionID = (int)questionIDdata[0].Row[0];
```

You should also `using System.Data;` at the top of the file

Comment: done! but I am getting error on "Item". Maybe Item is builtin method for VB and not for C#?
Error CS1061 'DataView' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no accessible extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'DataView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Ah, I forgot it's a Default indexer - you can just remove the word Item and index the dataview directly. I updated the answer.

Comment: Worked! thanks once again.